# How to prove that Feynman propagators of $U(1)$ spin-$1$ field are equivalent in Coulomb gauge and $R_\zeta$ gauge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-theory, propagator, gauge

How to prove that Feynman propagator are equivalent in Coulomb gauge and $R_\zeta$ gauge? (Be more specific, they are same when they contract with external current)

In $R_\zeta$ gauge, the propagator takes the form
$$
D_{F\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{k^2+i\epsilon}\left[g_{\mu\nu}-(1-\zeta)\frac{k_{\mu}k_\nu}{k^2}\right]
$$

When $\zeta=1$ it's the Feynman gauge, $D_{F\mu\nu}=-\frac{g_{\mu\nu} }{k^2+i\epsilon} $. It's the usual form we use in Feynman rules. 
Because the $A_{\mu}$ is always coupled to the conserved current，i.e. $\partial_\mu J^\mu(x)=0$ so $k_\mu J^{\mu}(k)=0$. So it proves that propagator in $R_{\zeta}$ gauge is equivalent to the Feynman gauge.

In Coulomb gauge, the propagator takes the form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
D^C_{F\mu\nu}&=\frac{1}{k^2+i\epsilon}\left(\sum_{i=1,2}\epsilon_\mu(k,i)\epsilon_\nu(k,i)\right)\\
&= -\frac{g_{\mu\nu} }{k^2+i\epsilon} -\frac{n_{\mu}n_{\nu}}{(k\cdot n)^2-k^2}-\frac{1} {k^2+i\epsilon} \frac{k_\mu k_\nu-(k_\mu n_\nu+k_\nu n_\mu  )(k.n)}{(k\cdot n)^2-k^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the same argument of above, the 3rd term has no contribution. But the second term is an instantaneous Coulomb interaction. If we choose $n^{\mu}=(1,0,0,0)$, the second the term is 
$$
\frac{\delta_{\mu,0}\delta_{\nu,0}}{|\mathbf{k}|^2}
$$

In coordinate space, this term is 
$$
\delta_{\mu,0}\delta_{\nu,0}\frac{\delta(x_0-y_0)}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}
$$

I can't see why it's zero when it couples with external current.

Comment: This term will *not* vanish. It's obvious why this is called Coulomb gauge, right? ;) in other gauges you have to work a bit harder to extract this term. Try using an explicit expression for $k=(E, p,0,0)$ and see how it works in Feynman gauge.

Comment: @rwold If it's not vanishing, how to prove Coulomb gauge is equivalent to Feynman gauge?

Comment: It has to vanish on the physical (transverse) polarizations, right? I am not sure what you mean by equivalence, but for what I know as long as they have the same S-matrix they can be considered equivalent.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I  want to prove the instantaneous Coulomb interaction vanishes when  instantaneous Coulomb interaction contract with externel source. But it seems impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term
$$
\delta_{\mu0}\delta_{\nu0}\frac{\delta(x_0-y_0)}{4\pi|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}|}
$$
does **not** vanish on its own. Rather, it is cancelled by the instantaneous (non-local) Coulomb term
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal L_\mathrm{Coul.}&=\frac12\int\mathrm d\boldsymbol y\ \frac{1}{4\pi|\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol y|}J^0(x^0,\boldsymbol x)J^0(x^0,\boldsymbol y)\\
&=\frac12\int\mathrm dy\ \delta_{\mu0}\delta_{\nu0}\frac{\delta(x^0-y^0)}{4\pi|\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol y|}J^\mu(x)J^\nu(y) 
\end{aligned}
$$

For more details, see [Srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html), chapters 55 and 56.

Comment: See also [Bjorken, Drell](https://www.amazon.com/Relativistic-Quantum-Fields-James-Bjorken/dp/0070054940), chapter 17.9.

Comment: Oh~I see . In Coulomb gauge with external source, $A^0$ is decided by external source. So there will be a nonlocal term in original Lagrangian. Thanks.

Comment: @fff123123 exactly :-) I'm glad I could help.